# Possible to set each element make total 100% width in css?

Tags: jquery, css, width

I have a div contener 100% with some div in it,
 but i cannot know the number of div generated in it (generate by php)
Question seems stupid but, point is we don't know the number of element , so i need to set the width of each element in % for taking 100% of contener.

if i know the number of element i make simply:

```
<div id = "contener" "style= width : 100% ">

  <div "style = width : 20% ">
  <div "style = width : 20% ">
  <div "style = width : 20% ">
  <div "style = width : 20% ">
  <div "style = width : 20% ">

  </div>


 Is it possible in css to achieve it 
 without knowing the number elements generated in the contener ?
```

Comment: Why not setting the width when `php` returns the `div`s?|
* Please show the code that creates those div elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;` for creating it. For creating equal sized column use `table-layout: fixed;`.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="col">Column #1</div>
    <div class="col">Column #2</div>
    <div class="col">Column #3</div>
    <div class="col">Column #4</div>
    <div class="col">Column #5</div>
    <div class="col">Column #6</div>
    <div class="col">Column #7</div>
        <!-- and so on ... -->
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.parent{
   width:100%;
   display: table;
   table-layout: fixed;
}
.parent .col{
   display: table-cell;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/YhpzF/)

Comment: thx, it works, hope its not too dirty with table :) , but if its the only solution..

Comment: Is there any advantages of a jquery solution ?!

Comment: @albator No advantage for jQuery, But disadvantage for `table`s if you're going to use it for layout purposes. tables are considered for tabular data.

Comment: seems not friendly with mobile, anyway thanks for both solution

Answer (score 1):

As a pure CSS solution, you could use `table` element or CSS table, as follows:

```css
.parent {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.row { display: table-row; }

.col { display: table-cell; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">Column #1</div>
        <div class="col">Column #2</div>
        <div class="col">Column #3</div>
        <div class="col">Column #4</div>
        <div class="col">Column #5</div>
        <div class="col">Column #6</div>
        <div class="col">Column #7</div>
        <!-- and so on ... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/XQWf5/)**

Or use JavaScript to calculate the width of each column

Using jQuery:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var cols = $('.parent .col');
    cols.width($('.parent').width()/cols.length);
}).resize(); // trigger resize handler
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/XQWf5/3/)**

Comment: nice solution, your fiddle link is empty though. Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nf33w/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do a calculation with jQuery:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
var $cols = $('.container > .col');
var numberOfCols = $cols.length;

$cols.css('width', 100/numberOfCols + '%');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gAB47/)